# Remove empty ul's in blade template foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I have foreach loops in my blade where I show categories and sub-categories. This is the part from the blade

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <h1>Categories</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked cat-nav">
      @foreach($menu as $category_menu)
         @if($menu->has('subcategories'))    
             <li>
                <a href="#">{{ $menu['category_name'] }}</a>
                 <ul>
                    @if($menu->subcategories->count())                 
                       @foreach($menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
                          @if($subcategory->products->count())
                              <li><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
                          @endif
                       @endforeach                      
                    @endif
                 </ul>
             </li>
             @else
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $menu->category_name }}</span></a></li>
         @endif          
      @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

This create folowing html

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked cat-nav">                                  
    <li>
        <a href="#">Category_1</a>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Sub Category in Category_1</a>
               </li>                                                    
           </ul>
    </li>                                                                 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Category_2</a>
           <ul>
           </ul>
    </li>                    
</ul>
```

You can see the empty `ul` under `Category_2` because `Category_2` doesn't have any assigned sub-categories to it the `ul` element is empty. Maybe is easy fix but I've tried to play around with loops but can't fix it.

Comment: Move `ul` inside `if`?

Comment: @u_mulder it was inside and was same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `<ul>` inside `@if($subcategory->products->count())` with a condition if it is already declared or not to prevent seperating all of the list in `<ul></ul>`. Then add `</ul>` condition after the loop.

```
@if($menu->subcategories->count())          
     @foreach($menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
         <?php $ul = false; //Create a temporary variable to validate if <ul> is already declared ?>
         @if($subcategory->products->count())
           @if(!$ul) 
            <?php $ul = true; ?> 
            <ul>
           @endif
             <li><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
           @if($ul)
             </ul> <!-- End ul here -->
           @endif 
         @endif
     @endforeach 

@endif
```

Comment: With this I get one less closing </ul> so after `Category_1` everything goes in inner ul which is open..

Comment: The code above still doesn't work as expected. Now there is one `<ul>` less

Comment: Oh I see. I updated my answer again. Put the declaration inside ``@foreach($menu->subcategories as $subcategory)`` and </ul> inside ``@if($subcategory->products->count())`` in the end. 

But I notice something. Are you going to loop the ``$subcategory->products``? Because in your post it is not. If it is not then you can just do ``<ul><li><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li></li>``. Simple as that.

Comment: I think I loop `$subcategory->products` because if sub-category is assigned to main category BUT there is not products assigned to sub-category It wont be shown on the menu. Is that what you asking?

Answer (score 2):

You have to move `ul` under `if` condition like:

```
@if($menu->subcategories->count())                 
<ul>
   @foreach($menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
      @if($subcategory->products->count())
          <li><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
      @endif
   @endforeach                      
</ul>
@endif
```

So that `ul` is generated when there is some data exist for it.

`Edit:` If still this is not working then change the condition from

```
$menu->subcategories->count()
```

to

```
count($menu->subcategories) > 0
```

Comment: If the ul is inside if doesn't show anything from the foreach.. just empty ul's

Comment: In that case change the condition from `$menu->subcategories->count()` to `count($menu->subcategories) > 0`

Comment: This is working. What is the difference between count and >0 .. isn't the result same?

Comment: I don't know why are you using `$menu->subcategories->count()`. When you are dealing with array you have to use `count( $variable )` to check if there is an element in the array or not.

Comment: I think this can still show empty ``<ul>`` if all of its ``@if($subcategory->products->count())`` are false. That can happen. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, true. I've tried it and is showing empty ul's when `@if($subcategory->products->count())`

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you may add a new attribute to the `$menu` which will hold a boolean value whether any subcategory has products or not:

```
$menu->subcategoriesHaveProducts = $menu->subcategories->map(function($subcategory) use($menu) {
    return !$subcategory->products->isEmpty() || $menu->subcategoriesHaveProducts;
});
```

After that you must change the if condition to check if the menu has any subcategory:

```
@foreach($menu as $category_menu)
     @if($menu->has('subcategories'))    
         <li>
            <a href="#">{{ $menu['category_name'] }}</a>
              @if($menu->subcategories->count() && $menu->subcategoriesHaveProducts)

              <ul>
                   @foreach($menu->subcategories as $subcategory)
                      @if($subcategory->products->count())
                          <li><a href="#">{{$subcategory->sub_cat_name}}</a></li>
                      @endif
                   @endforeach
             </ul>                      
             @endif
         </li>
         @else
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>{{ $menu->category_name }}</span></a></li>
     @endif          
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the controller or in my Model?

Comment: it is better to do it in the controller